# Display custom description near username

Tags: linux, terminal

I'd like to add a custom text nearby my username when I'm logging into my box, for example:
"**ATTENTION PRODUCTION SERVER!** username@hostname:~$"

"**UAT** username@hostname:~$"

"**QA** username@hostname:~$"

Which file I have to edit?

Answer (score 0):

try editing `.bash_profile` in user home dir, or `/etc/profile` (all user).

variable to be set is `PS1`.